# Bind route to custom physical path in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I want to set up the routes to open views depend on the custom parameter "theme",
like this:

```
http://localhost/black/home   to open  ~/themes/black/views/home/index.cshtml
http://localhost/white/home   to open  ~/themes/white/views/home/index.cshtml
```

the name of theme is dynamic, and I registered routes like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute("ThemeRoute", "{theme}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
        , new
        {
            theme = "default",
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
```

but it doesn't work. How could I bind the custom route "{theme}/{controller}/{action}/{id}" to the custom physical path like "~/themes/{theme}/views/{view}/{action}"? or impossible?
I'd appreciate if anyone could give me advices.

**Update:**
I decompiled the class `System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine` and find out how to define my own custom physical path, like this:

```
  public sealed class ThemeViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
  { 
        private ThemeViewEngine(IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator)
            : base(viewPageActivator)
        {
            //...
            AreaViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                "~/Areas/{2}/Themes/{3}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Areas/{2}/Themes/{3}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
            };
            //...
        }
  }
```

then override the method `FindView` and added the engine to `ViewEngines.Engines` in Global.asax, now the ViewEngine can find view pages in my defined paths.But the route still don't accept the url `{theme}/{controller}/{action}/{id}`,it seems that the route can't recognize the {theme} is the same thing with what has the same name in the engine. so I use the query string and cookie to control the theme for now,like this:

```
http://localhost/home?theme=black   to open  ~/themes/black/views/home/index.cshtml
http://localhost/home?theme=white   to open  ~/themes/white/views/home/index.cshtml
```

but it's not prefect, I still need help or find the way by myself.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Areas to organized your two themes. You can have two areas: "Black" and "White". Each of them has its own controllers and actions. 
The route pattern would be: {AreaName}/{Controller}/{Action}/{Id}.
Check this link for how to use areas.
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/article.php/c20227/Using-Areas-in-ASPNET-MVC-Application.htm

Comment: Thank you Jun Guo, but I'm afraid I can't use areas for this, because if I want to use "theme" and "area" at the same time, it'll be a problem again.